# Validar bastidor y matrícula con expresiones regulares en Java

Tags: java, regex

Tengo dos campos: **Bastidor** y **matricula**. Quiero validar ambos jTextField.

Bastidor: número de caracteres exacto = 15. De lo contrario mensaje de alerta en pantalla.
Matricula: Son 4 números + 3 letras. Formato: `nnnnXXX`. De lo contrario mensaje de alerta en pantalla.

Mi duda está en que al ser `keyTiped` comprueba carácter a carácter si se pasa de 15 o no llega a 15, pero siempre no va a llegar ni a 2, en el primer carácter dará el error

**Código**:

```
private void textfield_bastidorKeyTyped (java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {   
    if (textfield_bastidor.getText().length() >= 15) {
        evt.consume();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "El bastidor tiene una longitud de 15 caracteres.");
    }
}                                           

private void textfield_matriculaKeyTyped (java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{3}$");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(textfield_matricula.getText());
    if (mat.matches()) {
        System.out.println("codigo de que es correcto");
    } else {
        System.out.println("codigo de que es incorrecto");
    }
}
```

Comment: necesitas validar cada vez que ingresa un caracter o quieres validarlo una vez que termine de escribir el usuario?

Comment: Una vez que termine de escribir o caracter a caracer viene siendo lo mismo debido a que debe comprobar si ha escrito 6 o ha escrito 19... solo lo valida con 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el primer caso, ocupe tu codigo y funciona perfecto, no veo el error.

En el segundo caso, cuando ejecutas el evento `keyPress` o `keyTyped` el primer valor que entra es vacio. Si escribes en tu `textfield` 1, en primera instancia aparecera vacio, en segunda instancia si agregas un dos (es decir 12) mostrara 1.

Hay un evento tambien llamado `keyReleased` que trae el valor exacto cuando el usuario suelta un tecla. Ademas de que tu expresion regular estaba mal, debes hacerlo en este evento.

```
KeyListener keyListener2 = new KeyListener() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^\\d{4}[A-Z]{3}");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(textField2.getText());
        if (mat.matches()) {
            System.out.println("codigo de que es correcto");
        } else {
            System.out.println("codigo de que es incorrecto");
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    }
};

textField2.addKeyListener(keyListener2);
```

La expresión regular que te di, acepta el formato nnnnAAA (4 numeros y 3 letras) siendo :

- ^ Indica que es una cadena
- \d Indica numero de un digito (0-9)
- {4} que espera la cantidad de 4 para el patron anterior
- [A-Z] letras de la A a la Z
- {3} que espera la cantidad de 3 para el patron anterior

**EDICION**

Ya que entendimos mejor el problema del primer caso, puedes intentar algo asi :

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("El bastidor debe tener 15 caracteres");

getContentPane().add(myLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (textField1.getText().length() == 15) {
            myLabel.setVisible(false);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "El bastidor tiene una longitud de 15 caracteres.");
        } else {
            myLabel.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

    }
};
textField1.addKeyListener(keyListener);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el primer caso sí existe un error, debido a que si insertas 12 caracteres te lo da por válido y no debería ser así, solo debe aceptar la longitud de 15 caracteres, ni menos ni mas, exactamente 15.

Comment: ahhh!! es que por eso te habia comentado que te explicara,s solo tienes que cambiar la comparacion de >= por !=

Comment: pero con KeyTyped te va a dar error a la primera tecla que insertes. Si inserto una tecla, compruebo si la longitud es 15, y como no lo es, pues mensaje de error, y volvemos a empezar.

Comment: el problema esta ahi, en que nunca va a ser 15, mientras no ingrese 15, por lo tanto segun tu codigo DEBE enviar el mensaje. Lo que yo haria es mostrar un Jlabel al lado que diga que debe ser de 15 y ocultarlo cuando sea 15 exactamente

Comment: buena idea que no se me había ocurrido. O mostrar un mensaje informativo en un jLabel y a la hora de insertar insertar/enviar/mandar_formulario comprobar que son 15 y si no lo son ahora sí mostrar el mensaje de error y mandar el foto al campo jTextField erróneo.

Comment: exacto!, ya que si quieres evaluar letra por letra y enviar una alerta, es muy incomodo para el usuario

Comment: @omaza1990 edite!, obviamente puedes tu editar el style y todo eso